# Scanner and Whitespace

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How does the java.util.Scanner object react to whitespace characters? Specifically, if the next character in a text file is newline or space, would Scanner.next() return the newline or space, or would it return the next non-whitespace character? And, if only whitespace characters remain in a file, would Scanner.hasNext() return true or false? The documentation mentions that it only picks up "complete tokens," but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: You can set a custom delimiter. I think it eats the delimiter e.g. the new lines by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods in order to capture those lines that contain only a whitespace.

It's all about the positioning of the cursor , next() method positions the cursor on the same line after reading the input , while nextLine() positions the cursor on the next line after reading a given input.

This article explains this difference quite clearly, and hope that would answer your question as well.

https://www.javaartifacts.com/difference-next-nextline/

Scanner breaks it's inputs into tokens and the default delimiter is whitespace. So if you wanna customise this default delimiter and use your own delimiter like example a comma , then you can invoke the following method on your scanner class object :

s.useDelimiter(",");

For more information refer the following documentation :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html